# Split by RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a way to split this string based on comma ','.

```
"saleHours.sunTo(saleHours.satTo, saleHours.satFrom), saleHours.funTest(saleHours.sunFrom)"
```

However this is the desired result:

`["saleHours.sunTo(saleHours.satTo, saleHours.satFrom)", saleHours.funTest(saleHours.sunFrom)"]`

Not this:

`["saleHours.sunTo(saleHours.satTo", " saleHours.satFrom)", " saleHours.funTest(saleHours.sunFrom)"]`.

So I somehow need to escape the commas within '()'.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just curious: what do you plan on doing with the result? Those lines look a lot like code...

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a template engine, and I need to somehow register that the user is trying to call a function. I'm actually pretty close to nailing this down, but sadly nested functions is what I'm struggling with now

Comment: That seems kinda dubious, to be honest... Be _very_ careful with validating what the user is entering.

Comment: I'm trying to build and express template engine, entering something invalid will break the template for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input = "saleHours.sunTo(saleHours.satTo, saleHours.satFrom), saleHours.funTest(saleHours.sunFrom)";

    var m = input.split(/\),/);
    var l = m.length;
    for(i in m)
    {
        if(i<l-1)
            m[i] = m[i]+")";
    }

    console.log(m);
```

output:

```
[ 'saleHours.sunTo(saleHours.satTo, saleHours.satFrom)',
  ' saleHours.funTest(saleHours.sunFrom)' ]
```

Comment: Seems to work properly. However, I'd suggest `trim`-ing the results also.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you have any other requirements but this code splits the string in the last comma:

```
str.split(/[\s,]+/)
```

Comment: He didn't say he had.

Comment: Thank you, Richard Morais, but yes I should have been more clear. The idea was to be able to split the string based on external commas regardless of how many elements there are.

Comment: You may find a way using one of those regex generators online like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yes, struggling with that currently :)